# Problems Customizing WPF MenuItems

Tags: wpf, controltemplate

I am new to WPF and trying to get the hang of customizing UI elements.

**First Problem:**

I am trying to customize the background and foreground colors (and borders) for all states of the MenuItems and I can't seem to find all the properties that need to be changed. I have successfully changed all of the colors with one exception: When the menu is opened, the submenu items have a gray box around them and I can't figure out how to change the properties of the gray box.

**Details:**

I have read numerous posts here and elsewhere and it seems clear that I need to create a control template for the menu items. After numerous attempts to do that from scratch, I decided to use VS to create a copy of the default template (MenuItem properties -> convert to new resource).

Using that template solved most of my problems, with one exception, the sub menu items have a gray box around them like so: [image of open menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aa7Mo.gif)

Can anyone tell me how I change the color of the gray box?

**Second Problem:**

While the template solves most of my problem, it seems to create another one. When I configure a menu item to use the template, I see the visual changes in the UI, however the menu item stops opening the submenus when clicked. The Click event still fires and the event handler in the code behind works fine, it just won't open and display the menu items inside it.

Any help would be appreciated. I hope I am just missing something simple. I have seen some fairly knarly examples of control customization. I hope I don't need to go that far just to change a background color on mouseover.

Thanks.

Here is the template as it stands now.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuItemControlTemplate1"
                 TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Border x:Name="templateRoot"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Grid Margin="-1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="13" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup"
                                  Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon"
                              Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}"
                              ContentSource="Icon"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              Height="16"
                              Margin="3"
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                              Width="16" />
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="menuHeaderContainer"
                              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                              Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                              Grid.Column="1"
                              ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}"
                              ContentSource="Header"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                              Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                              RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="menuGestureText"
                       Grid.Column="3"
                       Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                       Opacity="0.7"
                       Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Icon"
                 Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility"
                    TargetName="Icon"
                    Value="Collapsed" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                 Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility"
                    TargetName="Icon"
                    Value="Collapsed" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted"
                 Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    TargetName="templateRoot"
                    Value="#fcfce8" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    TargetName="templateRoot"
                    Value="LightGoldenrodYellow" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="Black" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                 Value="False">
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground"
                    TargetName="templateRoot"
                    Value="#FF707070" />
        </Trigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsHighlighted"
                           Value="True" />
                <Condition Property="IsEnabled"
                           Value="False" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    TargetName="templateRoot"
                    Value="#FF808080" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    TargetName="templateRoot"
                    Value="#FF808080" />
        </MultiTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Want to try this?

[image: menu]

It's a bit long.

```
<!-- change color here (I think, do not remember) -->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.MenuTextBrushKey}" Color="White" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.MenuBarBrushKey}" Color="#3E3939" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.MenuColorKey}" Color="#5D5C5C" />


<!-- Menu Inicio -->


<!-- Menu -->

<Style  TargetType="{x:Type Menu}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.MenuBarBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemFonts.MenuFontFamilyKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemFonts.MenuFontSizeKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemFonts.MenuFontStyleKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemFonts.MenuFontWeightKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.MenuTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Menu}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!-- Nivel 0 -->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelItemTemplateKey}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Grid x:Name="Grid" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <Path x:Name="GlyphPanel" Data="F1M10,1.2L4.7,9.1 4.5,9.1 0,5.2 1.3,3.5 4.3,6.1 8.3,0 10,1.2z" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Margin="3" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="1" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
            <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom" >
                <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="#FF999999" BorderThickness="1" Background="White" Padding="2">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                        <Grid x:Name="Grid1" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                            <Canvas x:Name="Canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}"/>
                            </Canvas>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle" Fill="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,2,0,2" Width="1"/>
                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter"  KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </Popup>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#3D26A0DA"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF26A0DA"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF707070"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#FF707070"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="CanContentScroll" SourceName="SubMenuScrollViewer" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<!-- Nivel 0 -->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Grid x:Name="Grid" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <Path x:Name="GlyphPanel" Data="F1M10,1.2L4.7,9.1 4.5,9.1 0,5.2 1.3,3.5 4.3,6.1 8.3,0 10,1.2z" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Margin="3" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="1" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
            <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom" >
                <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="#FF999999" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.MenuColorKey}}" Padding="2">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                        <Grid x:Name="Grid1" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                            <Canvas x:Name="Canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}"/>
                            </Canvas>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle" Fill="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,2,0,2" Width="1"/>
                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter"  KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </Popup>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#3D26A0DA"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF26A0DA"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF707070"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#FF707070"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="CanContentScroll" SourceName="SubMenuScrollViewer" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<!-- Nivel 1,2,3,4,... -->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Grid Margin="-1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="22" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="13"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
            <Border x:Name="GlyphPanel" BorderBrush="#FF26A0DA" BorderThickness="1" Background="#3D26A0DA" Height="22" Margin="-1,0,0,0" Visibility="Hidden" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="22" >
                <Path x:Name="Glyph" Data="{DynamicResource ŧ}" Fill="#FF212121" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Height="11" Width="9"/>
            </Border>
            <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="2" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Opacity="0.7" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Path x:Name="RightArrow" Grid.Column="5" Data="M0,0L4,3.5 0,7z" Fill="#FF212121" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" HorizontalOffset="-2" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Right" VerticalOffset="-3">
                <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="#FF999999" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.MenuColorKey}}" Padding="2">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                        <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                            <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                <!--Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" White  #FFF0F0F0-->
                                <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}"/>
                            </Canvas>
                            <Rectangle Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,2,0,2" Width="1"/>
                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </Popup>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF26A0DA"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF707070"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Glyph" Value="#FF707070"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="RightArrow" Value="#FF707070"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="CanContentScroll" SourceName="SubMenuScrollViewer" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
<!-- Nivel 1,2,3,4,... -->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuItemTemplateKey}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Grid Margin="-1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="22" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="13"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
            <Border x:Name="GlyphPanel" BorderBrush="#FF26A0DA" BorderThickness="1" Background="#3D26A0DA" ClipToBounds="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="22" Margin="-1,0,0,0" Visibility="Hidden" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="22">
                <Path x:Name="Glyph" Data="F1M10,1.2L4.7,9.1 4.5,9.1 0,5.2 1.3,3.5 4.3,6.1 8.3,0 10,1.2z" Fill="#FF212121" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Height="11" Width="10"/>
            </Border>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="menuHeaderContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="2" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="menuGestureText" Grid.Column="4" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Opacity="0.7" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#3D26A0DA"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF26A0DA"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF707070"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Glyph" Value="#FF707070"/>
        </Trigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#0A000000"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#21000000"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<!-- Menu Fim -->
```

**MainWindows.xaml example**

```
<Menu IsMainMenu="True" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Visibility="Visible"  >
    <MenuItem Header="Arquivo" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0"   >
        <MenuItem Header="Importação de Resultados" Command="{Binding MenuCommand}" CommandParameter="ImportacaoViewModel" >
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Image Source="Images/add.png" Height="20"/>
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
        <Separator />
        <MenuItem Header="Sair" Command="{Binding MenuCommand}" CommandParameter="LogOff" >
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Image Source="Images/excluir.png" Height="20"/>
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
.............
```

Comment: Ok, this shows me there are a lot more moving parts than I originally thought. Thanks @Celso, this works great.